# The embedding of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ (The space of tempered distributions)

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

This question came into my mind when I was reading an example on *Reed and Simon* Vol. 1, in the section on "Functions of rapid decrease and the tempered distributions".

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of rapid decreasing functions (or "Schwartz space" in some books) and $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ its topological dual. Take $g\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and one can easily see that $g(\cdot)$ given by
$$g(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\phi(x)dx$$
defines an element in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore, the map 
\begin{eqnarray}
\mu: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})&\longrightarrow&\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}) \\
g &\longmapsto& g(\cdot)
\end{eqnarray}
is well defined.
The author argued the injectivity of this map by saying that  **since $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $L^2$, $g_1\neq g_2$ in $\mathcal{S}$ implies $g_1\neq g_2$ in $L^2$, which implies $g_1\neq g_2$ in $(L^2)^*$, which, in turn, implies $g_1\neq g_2$ in $\mathcal{S}'$**.

I would like to seek the proper understanding to this sentense. In my opinion, the first implication (from $\mathcal{S}$ to $L^2$) is because $\mathcal{S}\subseteq L^2$ and being different in a subspace implies being different in a larger space. The second implication (from $L^2$ to $(L^2)^*$) is due to the correspondence by the Riesz lemma. I don't know how to exactly argue the third implication. Is this implication related to the density of $\mathcal{S}$ in $L^2$?

By the way, does this imply that $(L^2)^*$ is dense in $\mathcal{S}'$? (Note that the topology on $\mathcal{S}'$ is the weak * topology, so it's not quite clear whether this statement is true.)

I'd appreciate it if there is any argument for each implication which can bring more insights than mine (I don't quite like my own arguments above because they do not look concrete enough) or if there is any other way to show the injectivity of the map $\mu$. Thanks in advance for answers and comments.

Comment: $g(g)$ is not zero if $g$ is not zero, so the map is injective.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thanks. This sounds convincing to me. Am I right to say that the density of $\mathcal{S}$ in $L^2$ plays no role here? It's a bit amazing to me why the Reed and Simon used such a long logical chain when this concise one-line proof is available.

Comment: But one needs to prove that $g(\phi)=0$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$ implies $g=0$, and one way to do this is to use the density of $\mathcal S$ in $L^2$. Of course, more elementary arguments are possible (for $g\neq 0$ construct $\phi\in \mathcal S$ such that $g(\phi)\neq 0$).

Comment: The third implication indeed uses the density of $\mathcal S$ in $L^2$ once again: Two continuous maps that coincide on a dense subset coincide on the whole space.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks. I think you are right. That should be the general way. Suggested by Mariano, I argued that g()=0 implies that $g(g^*)=0$ and therefore g=0 in the $L^2$ norm. So g=0, a.e. Since g is in $\mathcal{S}$, its continuity makes it a 0 function. I hope this argument is also correct? Thanks for pointing out the general usage of the density!

Comment: I think you just re-stated the argument by Reed and Simon in a more explicit way (and therefore it's absolutely fine). As for your last question, $L^2$ (and even $\mathcal S$) is indeed dense in $\mathcal S'$, but that doesn't follow from the above reasoning (remember that the topology on $\mathcal S$ is quite different from that on $L^2$).

Comment: @MaoWao Ah. Now I see the entire logic. At first I failed to see how the two arguments are related. Now I can see that I was really just re-stating that (in the contrapositive way). Thanks